# Qt creator debug mode has disappeared

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt-creator

I was working with Qt both in debug mode and release mode before I update my packages by update manager in Ubuntu 12.04. After Updating I couldn't debug my code. By looking at Project Mode in Qt, all I see is Release Mode:

- One is "**Qt 4.8.1 (System) Release**"
  ,
- and the other one is "**Qt 4.8.1 in PATH (System) Release**"

I put the screen shot of my program in [here](http://tinypic.com/r/r91i52/8)
What should I do ? Why debug mode has disappeared ? Does updating the packages caused this issue ? I'm sure that I didn't change any Qt settings in the last week.

Comment: Perhaps you can ask this question in [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: Check your debugger path in `Build & Run>Debuggers`. Also check the debugger option in kits.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your debug configuration got corrupted or removed. I'd suggest attempt to recreate it:

1. Open *Projects* tab (ctrl+5)
2. Select your project from the top projects lists
3. Select *Build & Run* page
4. Choose: *Desktop/Build*
5. --> *Build Settings* -> *Edit build configuration: Debug* --> *Add*

Based on QtC 2.8, but should be similar on newer versions.

Comment: I am using Qt creator 2.4.1 and these steps can not be applied to it. I didn't find 4 and 5 in my qtcreator ...